# Python3: How to round up to a specific number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to round up to the next 1, 2 or 5 decimal value like in the following code example.

```
        if result > 0.1:
            if result > 0.2:
                if result > 0.5:
                    if result > 1.0:
                        if result > 2.0:
                            if result > 5.0:
                                if result > 10.0:
                                    if result > 20.0:
                                        if result > 50.0:
                                            rounded_result = 100.0
                                        else:
                                            rounded_result = 50.0
                                    else:
                                        rounded_result = 20.0
                                else:
                                    rounded_result = 10.0
                            else:
                                rounded_result = 5.0
                        else:
                            rounded_result = 2.0
                    else:
                        rounded_result = 1.0
                else:
                    rounded_result = 0.5
            else:
                rounded_result = 0.2
        else:
            rounded_result = 0.1
```

E.g. for values between 0.1 and 0.2 rounded_result should be 0.2, for values between 0.2 and 0.5 rounded_result should be 0.5 and so on.

Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: What should happen if the value is larger than 100?

Comment: @MurrayW `if result>50.0: rounded_result=100.0` every number greater than 50 are rounded to 100.

Comment: so 101.0 would be 'rounded' to 100? 10,000,000 would be 'rounded' to 100?

Comment: @MurrayW to keep it simple, lets say values larger than 100 will not occur due to the formula wich returns the value ```result``` (I didn`t add it to this post as it is not part of the problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function like this, maybe?

It expects `thresholds` to be in ascending order.

```
def round_threshold(value, thresholds):
    for threshold in thresholds:
        if value < threshold:
            return threshold
    return value


thresholds = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0]

for test in (0.05, 0.15, 11.3, 74, 116):
    print(test, round_threshold(test, thresholds))
```

The output is

```
0.05 0.1
0.15 0.2
11.3 20.0
74 100.0
116 116
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if value <= threshold`?

Comment: Since your assuming the thresholds are ordered, you could probably use the `bisect` module to avoid a linear search (though it likely does not matter given how short the threholds list is). `bisect.bisect(thresholds, value)` would return the value's insertion point which is the index of the next threshold up, which you can return. If it returns `len(thresholds)` then you've fallen off the end of the list. You can either handle that condition explicitly or use slices to make it implicit (and somewhat hard to read): `(thresholds[bisect.bisect(thresholds, v):] or [v])[0]`.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `next` with a filtering generator: `next((t for t in thresholds if value < thresholds), value)` will return the first generated value matching the filter... or the default.

Answer (score 0):

```
thresholds = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0]

for i,thresh in enumerate(thresholds):
    if value<thresh:
        print(thresholds[i])
        break
    if value>thresholds[-1]:
        print(thresholds[-1])
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the vectorized alternative:

```
def custom_round(value, boundaries):
    index = np.argmin(np.abs(boundaries - value)) + 1
    if index < boundaries.shape[0]:
        return boundaries[index]
    else:
        return value

import numpy as np    

boundaries = np.array([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 
                   1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 
                   20.0, 50.0, 100.0])

## test is from @AKX (see other answer)
for test in (0.05, 0.15, 11.3, 74, 116):
   print(test, custom_round(test, boundaries))
```